# Is there a simple way to "roll your own forms" for mysql in php, for example in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, crm

I've been googling around for a really simple way of making what is, in effect, nothing more than an enhanced phpMyAdmin.

In a mysql database, I have:
Name, address, phone, website etc, plus 2 or 3 custom fields. This data is pulled out to make a website.

All I want is to be able to make a freeform form, a bit like Access, but for the web, and the only thing I want to do over and above normal field editing would be to have a list of when I contact them, what was said, and perhaps a reminder when the next action is due. It also needs to implement some basic permissions so that different users can access different subsets of the data.

I've looked at so many CRMs my mind is boggling, and they all do WAY more than I need. I don't have leads or accounts, all I have is the need to make sure than when I update the person's details, and for that data to be in the same DB as my site is generate from.

I'm happy to learn if I can get pointed in the right direction, and I have a feeling that something like what I want might lie in the direction of jquery. It's just that there's so much good jquery stuff about, I can't see the wood for the trees!

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just dumping form results into this database, and then adding a few fields worth of data on each entry, what's wrong with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

If phpMyAdmin doesn't quite do it for you, it sounds like you just want a simple little web application.

jQuery is probably barking up the wrong tree.  It's just a javascript library.  While you could certainly use it to spiff up your little application, it's not going to get you the core functionality you need.

I would just dig in and write a little PHP script that does exactly what you want.  Even if you're not very experienced, this would be a great learning project.

Comment: phpMyAdmin does exactly what you are looking for^^

Comment: Clearly OP wants something at least marginally more specialized than phpMyAdmin, which he's clearly aware of already.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I meant phpMyAdmin not phpMySql. It was a long day.
The thing with phpMyAdmin is...some of the people editing the DB are, um, quite senior. And they can only have access to their own data.
So phpmyadmin would be quite complex, not to mention the privacy issues when other users can see each other's data.

Anyway, as mentioned above, I think I have a good few suggestions to be going along with. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tools which will generate forms including Phpeanuts, phpFormGen, Delphi for PHP, PfP Studio, FormFields, phpMyEdit (and many more).

I've not looked at Radria for some time - previously, it was more of a CMS/page layout/mashup thing rather than a form generator though.

C.

Comment: Thank you! 
phpMyEdit seems to be the way to go.
djangoproject and rubyonrails look interesting.
PhpPeanuts seems to have ended development with an argument in the forum in 2008
phpFormgenerator hasn't been updated for 3 years - doesn't mean it's bad, just might not be good for support.
As I didn't get emailed that there was a reply, I also went on the hunt again, and this looks interesting too:
http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/

Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As has been said, you need to build a web interface.

One simple thing you can use is something like Django's admin panel or Ruby on Rails' script/generate scaffold functionality. If you can run Rails or Django, try those.

If you are tied into PHP, consider using one of the PHP frameworks. I'm no expert on them - some of my PHP-using friends have good stuff to say about Symfony (the alternatives: Cake, CodeIgniter, Zend). A bit of random Googling tells me that Symfony has an admin generator that may be quite like that of Django.

As has been said, jQuery won't do what you need, although you can use it.